# Adding new stylesheet parameters for custom Qt widgets

Tags: qt

I would like to add stylesheet options for a custom widget I have developed. We have extended the QPushButton to be a different colour and to flash when it is depressed. This has been done by adding a new property, background color down. And we set this in code. But I would like to set this instead using a Qt stylesheet entry, something like

```
QFlashingButton
{
    background-color-down: yellow;
    flashing-interval: 5;
}
```

I can see one way to do this, read out the stylesheet info using the stylesheet() method, then parse it for parameters relevant to my widget and set them. But I am wondering if there is some way to access the code Qt have themselves for processing stylesheets. At first sight of their code this seems perhaps not to be publically available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the parameter you want to control in the stylesheet is a QProperty, you can set it in the stylesheet using the syntax: `qproperty-<PROPERTY_NAME>: <PROPERTY_VALUE>`

I don't think property names can actually have dashes in them, so assuming your QProperties on your custom widget are actually backgroundColorDown and flashingInterval, then your stylesheet would look like:

```
QFlashingButton
{
    qproperty-backgroundColorDown: yellow;
    qproperty-flashingInterval: 5;
}
```

Comment: Yes, this solved my problem, thanks. As a related issue, I then found as the display properties of the widget had been initially set by stylesheet, I had to use setStyleSheet() to override them with the flashing color, rather than using setBackground(), which had no effect.